# R classify missing keywords as -NA-

Tags: r, keyword, text-mining, text-classification

I am new to R and I am working on categorizing text based upon keywords. I have reviews mentioned by users in a CSV file. I am importing only the first 50
reviews and categorizing them based upon the keywords encountered.

The following is performed via the code:

```
library(text2vec) # to create the dtm
library(tokenizers) # to help creating the dtm
library(reshape2) # to reshape the data from wide to long
library(tm)
app_r <- read.csv('my-tracks-reviews.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
description <- app_r$comment_text[1:50]

#Text Cleaning
text <- Corpus(VectorSource(description))
text <- tm_map(text, content_transformer(tolower))
text <- tm_map(text, removeNumbers)
text <- tm_map(text, removePunctuation)
text <- tm_map(text, removeWords,stopwords('english'))
#text <- tm_map(text, removeWords,c('crap','excellent')) #Additional words
text <- tm_map(text, stripWhitespace)
print(text)
dataframe <- data.frame(text=sapply(text,identity), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(dataframe)
df1 <- structure(list(keyword = c("gps", "signal", "battery", "map", "track", "tracks", "app", "update","updates"), 
                      category = c("S", "S", "P", "M", "M", "M", "O", "U","U")), .Names = c("Keyword", "Category"), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-9L))
df1

#Creating vocabulary
vocabulary <- vocab_vectorizer(create_vocabulary(itoken(df1$Keyword)))

# 2. create the dtm
dtm <- create_dtm(itoken(as.character(dataframe$text)),vocabulary)

# 3. convert the sparse-matrix to a data.frame
dtm_df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))
dtm_df$text <- dataframe$text
str(dtm_df)
# 4. melt to long format
df_result <- melt(dtm_df, id.vars = "text", variable.name = "Keyword")

# 5. combine the data, i.e., add category
df_final <- merge(df_result, df1, by = "Keyword")
df_final 
write.csv(df_final, file = "d:/R/testml/keywords.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

The output is written in CSV file whose format is as follows:

```
 Keyword                text                             Category
    app     really briliant app intuitive informative       O
    app         great app glad used tracks perfectly        O
    app              interesting app                        O
```

But my problem is that out of 50 entries that were imported, it stored the entries of only 33 classified reviews in the output CSV file, the other 17 were discarded, I need to mention them as Non Applicable (NA) entries and store them in the CSV file along with the others(mostly into 'NA' category).

Portion of the data in 'my-tracks-reviews' is as follows:

```
    **comment_text**    **rating**
 "really briliant app    it's intuitive and informative giving all the information you could need and seemingly very accurate."  5
"will not connect to gps    app does not connect to gps no matter how long i have it on. i have gps set on high accuracy and other settings appear to be set as these should be. the app is useless to me  if it can't track my workout."   1
"wish this would interest more with google now to provide weekly or monthly summaries."   5
"useless    does not talk to gps on the phone. 20 minute run no data."  1
"great app  so glad i used this it tracks perfectly."   4
"excellent  thank you." 5
"update i wish this app had quick sharing where i could view on any device without drive and ability to view on google maps instead of google earthadv version of maps cuz i do most of my home stuff on my tablet and exercise with my phone it just a hassle.. overall i like the app it needs a update to keep up with rest of the google products and become more competitive with other products." 4
"nice but needs work    used this app a few times now and every time it takes an age to locate my position via gps. changing to other apps i have that rely on gps they locate me straight away. return to this app and it is still searching. last time it took over five minutes to locate my position this took some of the enjoyment out of using this app. will continue to use this to see if it improves. 3/5."  3
"dr anand venugopal too good."  4
"very interesting app."   5
"brilliant  good solid app."    5
"like   like."  4
```

Where comment_text is one column and rating is another column holding the respective data.

Comment: Would be useful to add some portion of data from `my-tracks-reviews.csv`

Comment: As requested, the details have been added

Comment: the portion needed some quotes here and there. Are you aware of that? If quotes are missing then the csv will *not* be imported properly

Comment: Yes but since I am working only with the reviews I have not imported the ratings if that is what you are trying to say as comment_text and ratings are two separate columns in the CSV

Comment: please check the edits I made. I still haven't gotten your problem. I am still trying

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding and inconvenience from my side but could you specify exactly what is not clear to you?

Comment: I have a hunch that the data is messed up. Could you please add a link with the complete data?

Comment: Thank you for your patience here is the link http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=45776325662357180611

Comment: up the Irons! (will update ASAP)

Comment: I am getting `names(df_final)`:
` "Keyword"  "text"     "value"    "Category"` . you are missing `value` in your example

Comment: yeah, it was a just to keep track of something but commented it later with #, the value field is not important

Comment: Since I am not familiar with the package. could you simply put, mention the expected result (just to compare it with what we are actually getting)?

Comment: We are getting the particular 'keyword' from the text and it gets classified into the respective category as mentioned above in the output CSV section.

Comment: FYI the output csv  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06191756379043278431